# Chrome theme new tab background does not fill correctly

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-theme

I wanted to modify the [Black red shards theme](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/black-red-shards/jpjlkkaalgfbbegfnjoclhfidancjpch) for my personal use but as you can see from this picture below the background does not fill the entire height. This can be reproduced on macOS and stretching the window to it's full height (ignoring the dock) or in this case, in fullscreen. The background is 1920x1080 and my display is 1920x1200 which I suspect is the reason this is broken. Scaling my display to 1920x1080 stretches my screen making it ugly, so what are my options?

[image]

The relevant parts of the manifest.json file are here:

```
   "name": "Black red shards",
   "theme": {
      "colors": {
         "bookmark_text": [ 255, 0, 0 ],
         "button_background": [ 255, 0, 0, 1 ],
         "frame": [ 66, 116, 201 ],
         "ntp_background": [ 0, 2, 2 ],
         "ntp_text": [ 255, 0, 0 ],
         "tab_background_text": [ 255, 0, 0 ],
         "tab_text": [ 255, 0, 0 ],
         "toolbar": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
     "omnibox_text": [ 255, 0, 0 ]
      },
      "images": {
         "theme_frame": "images/theme_frame.jpeg",
         "theme_ntp_background": "images/theme_ntp_background.jpeg",
         "theme_tab_background": "images/theme_tab_background.png",
         "theme_toolbar": "images/theme_toolbar.jpeg"
      },
      "properties": {
         "ntp_background_alignment": "bottom",
         "ntp_background_repeat": "no-repeat"
      },
      "tints": {
         "buttons": [ 0, 1, 0.5 ]
      }
   },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Google has fixed the bug, it is now back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

You suspect correctly. Your option would be scaling up the resolution of the image so that it matches your monitor resolution. https://ibb.co/8XxsDH9 is a 1920x1200 image, the original scaled up.

Comment: I believe that Google has fixed the bug. It's back to normal now. Thanks anyway, I will mark this problem as solved by answering the question and marking it as the correct answer